# swift notification update app in background if user doesnt click on notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am trying to understand how I can update my app once I get a notification.

What I want to do is simply once the app get a notification I want to simply increment a value and store it like: `userDefaults.set(counter, forKey: "someKey")`

I know that I can do this easy if a user actually clicks on the notification and the app open.

But is there any way to do this even if the user doesnt click on the notification?

Answer (score 2):

Enable background-fetch and remote notifications in the background modes which can be found in capabilities in Xcode. 
If you send your notifications with "content-available" key set to 1, your app's app delegate method for remote notifications will be called. In that method you can store the new data to UserDefaults.

This is the method you need to implement in your app delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
```

Also, note that this will not work if the application is killed by the user. If your application is a VOIP app, you may use PushKit to make your app open in the background for data updates even when user has killed the app before.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `Remote Notification` option in background mode of capabilities.

When you enabled it you can use the delegate method to update value and store it in `userdefaults`

```
application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
```

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html)